# Ruby thread synchronization

Tags: ruby, multithreading

My process has two threads like the following

```
@semaphore = Mutex.new
.
.
.
.
thread_a = Thread.new {
  loop do
    #some work
    if(some_condition) 
      @semaphore.synchronize {
        @thread_b_running = false
      }
    end
  end
}

thread_b = Thread.new {
  while(@semaphore.synchronize { @thread_b_running }) do
    #thread_b's work
  end
}
thread_a.join
thread_b.join
```

Basically, `thread_a` and `thread_b` do some work in parallel, however when `thread_a` sees an event happen it needs to shut down `thread_b`. As you can see right now I am doing it by using a boolean protected by a mutex. I think this approach is not too bad performance wise since `thread_b` will almost always get the lock without waiting for it. However since I have not written a lot of multithreaded code I was wondering if there is a better way of doing what I'm doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only one of the threads is writing the variable, there is no need for a mutex. So a better way in your example is just removing the mutex.

Comment: I thought about that but wouldn't that cause a problem since writing to the variable is not an atomic operation? What if thread_a is partially through writing to that variable when thread_a gets removed from the cpu thread_b gets scheduled?

Comment: @Wooser990 Correct me if I'm wrong, but writing to a variable is an atomic operation (citation needed). Even if not, since it is a boolean, in the worst case thread_b will run once more - the same case of change `thread_b_running` to true moments before thread B start running. Correct?

Comment: A write to a variable is not an atomic operation http://moonbase.rydia.net/mental/blog/programming/atomic-operations-in-ruby.html. However you are right that in my case the worst case scenario is thread_b code running for one extra iteration (which in my case is acceptable). I have accepted your answer